# Дана целочисленная матрица размера 5×5. Переставить местами 4 и 5 строку

Tags: c#

Я написал код , думал получилось но нет .
Индекс вышел за матрицу я так понял не знаю как исправить .
Помогите пожалуйста !
Вот что я сделал :

```
  int n = 5;
            int[,] matrix = new int[n, n];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 9);
                    Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
               (matrix[4, i], matrix[5, i]) = (matrix[5, i], matrix[4, i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки ведь нумеруются с нуля, ведь так?
Значит, четвёртая по порядку строка имеет индекс 3, а пятая - индекс 4

```
(matrix[3, i], matrix[4, i]) = (matrix[4, i], matrix[3, i]);
```

Comment: Точно ! Спасибо большое помог !